# Call function map statement in makefile

Tags: makefile

This is a quote from [`make`'s docs about the `call` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Call-Function.html):

> The call function can be nested. Each recursive invocation gets its own local values for $(1), etc. that mask the values of higher-level call. Here is an implementation of a map function:
>
> ```
> map = $(foreach a,$(2),$(call $(1),$(a)))
> ```
>
> Now it can map a function that normally takes only one argument, such as origin, to multiple values in one step:
>
> ```
> o = $(call map,origin,o map MAKE)
> ```
>
> and end up with o containing something like ‘file file default’.

Can somebody take the pain to explain what are they trying to convey and explain the code:

```
 o = $(call map,origin,o map MAKE)
```

Comment: Please specify exactly what it is you do understand and what it is you do not understand about the part of the documentation you cited.

Comment: I understand the map statement and that the expression o but I don't understand the reduction of  `o = $(call map, origin, o map MAKE)` because it has o in that so I think it would go in Infinite loop.

Comment: Can somebody explain that what is achieved through this. I think its a recursive infinite loop.

Comment: I don't see why you think so.  this isn't even recursive, really.  This definition of `map` says, "for each word in `$(2)` (in this case that's `o map MAKE`, invoke the function named `$(1)` (in this case that's `origin`) on that word".  So this basically runs `$(origin o) $(origin map) $(origin MAKE)`.

Comment: Maybe you are confused because `o` is on the left side of the `=` sign and is also a parameter in the `call` statement on the right side? That might make it look like a recursive statement (but it is not). Is your question answered if `o` on the right side was replaced by any other variable -- say `p`?

Comment: That's correct I was exact thinking of mine. That o was on both side of expression. So I was confused that I might lead to infinite loop . Thanks for clarity.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MadScientist for explaination of the statement. It calrify my all doubt. Thank you very much !!!!!!!!!